# Date with Hawaii timezone makes invalid JavaScript date

Tags: javascript, date

For some reason, when I pass a date with a Hawaii time zone to JavaScript's `Date()` I get "invalid date", but any other time zone I don't. Is there a workaround for this?

```
var HAST = 'Wed, 31 Jul 2013 07:21:16 HAST';
var hawaiiTime = new Date(HAST);
console.log("Hawaii time: "+hawaiiTime);
// Hawaii time: Invalid Date

var PST = 'Wed, 31 Jul 2013 07:21:16 PST';
var pacificTime = new Date(PST);
console.log("Pacific time: "+pacificTime);
// Pacific time: Wed Jul 31 2013 09:21:16 GMT-0600 (MDT)
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDvQ6/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) only supports North American UT Offsets (See [Page 32](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-32)).

```
"EST" / "EDT" /         ; Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
"CST" / "CDT" /         ; Central:  - 6/ - 5
"MST" / "MDT" /         ; Mountain: - 7/ - 6
"PST" / "PDT" /         ; Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
```

For everything else, you should use the numeric value relative to UTC or GMT.  For HAST, this would be `UTC-1000` (10 Hours before UTC):

```
var HAST = 'Wed, 31 Jul 2013 07:21:16 UTC-1000';
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXFqA/)